# How come the partial derivative in the same point is different for the same function depends on the implicit function theorem applied.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-function-theorem

Given $(*)x^2 + y^2 +z^2 - 3xyz = 0$

and a fucntion $f(x,y,z) = xy^{2}z^{3}$

first section wants to show that equation $(*)$ defines a function $z = z(x,y)$ around point $(1,1,1)$  then find $f'_{x}(1,1,1)$
so it's not problem:

we create a function $g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 +z^2 - 3xyz$ and we show:

(1) $ g(1,1,1) = 0 $

(2) partial derivatives of $g(x,y,z)$ are elementary functions

(3)$g'_{z} = -1 \neq 0$

so $g(x,y,z)$ defines a function $z = z(x,y)$ around point $(1,1,1)$

$f'_{x} = y^{2} z^{3} + xy^{2} \cdot3z^{2}z'_{x} |_{(1,1,1)} = 1 + 3z'_{x}$

while $z'_{x} = -\frac{g'_{x}(1,1,1)}{g'_{z}(1,1,1)}$

We showed that with the implicit function theorem and we took the derivative of the function $f(x,y,z)$ with respect to $z$ being a function  $z(x,y)$ and we get $f'_{x}(1,1,1) = -2$. cool, no problem yet.

But in the other section, we are required to do the same thing, but this time show that

$(*)$ defines a function $y = y(x,z)$ around point $(1,1,1)$  then again, find $f'_{x}(1,1,1)$

We do the same thing for $y$ instead of $z$, so get a different derivative of the same function in the same point. We get $f'_{x}(1,1,1) = -1$ because we now respsected $y$ to be a function and not $z$

So I'm tackled by this because we get a different derivative for the same function in the same point, also how come on one hand $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ but if we look at it another way $y$ is a function of $x$ and $z$ yet I assume they can't both be a function in the same time ?

Comment: Could you show the equations you used? I mean the derivatives and how you found them.

Comment: This is totally unclear... What does $f(x,y,z)=xy^2 z^3$ have to do with $(*)$?

Comment: @Cure I showed in detail how they did the first section, the second section is the same but with $y$ and gives another result for the same derivative because now $y$ is a function and not $z$.

Comment: @HansLundmark It's just how the question was given, I've added more details now, they turn the equation $(*)$ into a function $g(x,y,z)$, if it helps in anyway understand.

Comment: Ok, now it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $f'_x(1,1,1)$ for this is *horrible* notation, so no wonder you're confused...

What they do is define a composite function, let's call it $F$, by
$$
F(x,y) = f(x,y,z(x,y))
.
$$
This function has partial derivatives $F'_x(x,y)$ and $F'_y(x,y)$ which can be found using the chain rule,
and it's $F'_x(1,1)$ that you're computing.

Next they define another composite function
$$
G(x,z) = f(x,y(x,z),z)
$$
and ask you to compute $G'_x(1,1)$.

Comment: That makes so much more sense, thanks!